# Ignite cluster communication with multiple nics

Tags: ignite

Ignite uses one network card during a re-balance. It should use multiple.

Our cluster using more than 1gbps bandwidth during re-balance, so we tried network bonding but ARP cache needs to be refresh. Instead we want to use separate network devices on a virtual machine. But ignite uses one of them per re-balancing. Virtual machines are centos7. ignite is 2.7.0-1

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>ip1:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>ip2:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>ip3:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

We expect ignite to re-balance trough ip1, ip2, ip3 at the same time.

UPDATE

We've made a bonded virtual network device with combining multiple devices, unfortunately it has required some down time. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

- Can you create a virtual NIC which will join two physical ones together? I think this should be doable.
- Failing that, you can have two nodes per VM, one with localAddress nic1 and other with localAddress nic2. Please note that you should define localAddress on `TcpCommunicationSpi` since that's where traffic is. Share RAM fairly between those two nodes.

Maybe you could also have a custom TcpCommunicationSpi which will use two NICs, but I'm not sure if traffic will be distributed fairly even then.